# Getting error when try to convert "0.0" to empty string using nullif()

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I am try to convert a decimal field null values("0.0") into empty string ("") using nullif() method. But the conversion causing an error. I tried the same method for another int field, and it worked fine.

How can I convert decimal null values into empty strings in a sql queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SQL uses single quotes for `'values'`, double quotes for `"column labels"`
2. `'0.0'` is a string (for varchar columns), `0.0` and `0` are numbers (for int / dec columns)
3. neither `'0.0'` nor `0.0` are `null`s
4. `nullif()` returns `null` for the right condition, not an empty string

so you probably want something like this:

```
case when mydecimal = 0 then '' else cast(mydecimal as varchar(10)) end
```

or:

```
nullif(mydecimal, 0)
```

Comment: Yes it works, and I used nullif(myfield, ' ' ) like this, and it converts null to empty string except decimal fields. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

in TSQL : ISNULL(value, '') called the coalesce operator if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: or use the COALESCE builtin function itself. you would have to cast the value from decimal first but at the end of the day both ISNULL or COALESCE offer a shorter notation than CASE and more intuitive than NULLIF.